# How to launch ECS cluster in default VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

Is this possible? I would like to use elasticache, which seems to only be allowed to be created in my default VPC (alternative question is: How can I launch elasticache in a custom VPC), however I can't connect to it in a separate VPC. I don't know how to configure my clusters (or launch them outside of the "Getting Started")so that I can launch them in an existing VPC that I can set.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create the elasticache instance in the VPC created by the ECS cluster. Though, you'll need to create a cache subnet group first. See: [ElastiCache (redis) for non default VPC](https://serverfault.com/questions/610183/elasticache-redis-for-non-default-vpc)